# Python - Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-2.7

I am using [REPL.it](https://repl.it/languages/python) to run Python for my homework. When typing in and running this line of code:

```
# print "This will not run"
```

I get an unexpected EOF error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1
    # print "This will not run"
                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: That's too bad. Good lucking find it. We obviously can't, since you've shown nothing useful, like actual code.

Comment: Are you running just that ONE line of code, that's only a comment, not actual code?

Comment: That's the only line of code in my file

Comment: Then remove the `#` from the beginning of that line.

Comment: No I'm trying to make it a comment. I'm learning from pythonthehardway.org

Comment: Clearly your Python interpreter is expecting code, and you are not giving it any.  (A comment does not count as code.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with [REPL.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3), not with Python. I am not sure what the internals of that interpreter are, but it appears that REPL.it will not allow a comment as the first line of code if there is no other code. To illustrate, try the following:

```
foo = 1
# print "This will not run"
```

The interpreter should spit out `None` instead of raising an error. It seems that it also works to have a comment on the first line and an empty line (or a line with code) as the second line, but running a file in this app that consists of only a single comment line does not seem to work.

If you have access to Python on your computer (which you do by default if you are on Mac OSX or Linux), then I would suggest trying your examples in a real Python interpreter. Otherwise, you might see some unexpected results, as I assume that repl.it is not a full-featured interpreter (as indicated by the syntax error).

Answer (score 1):

It means Python is surprised that that the code ended without being finished. For your example, you didn't write any code, just a comment, without a blank line on the bottom?

Answer (score -1):

Try `print "This will not run"` if that's the ONLY line of code in your file.

Comment: That's the point, you're not 'running' code by running a commented line. If that's your only line of code, you may as well execute an empty file. And try this one instead: http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Overview/

Comment: Still, under normal circumstances, you would not expect the OP's commented code to raise a `SyntaxError`, would you?

Comment: Nope, I tried it myself to make sure. But it's a different setup OP is working with (not 'normal'), so my assumption, confirmed by others here I think, is that it won't like a commented line as the first and sole line in a 'code' file.

Answer (score -1):

The python-interpreter is looking for code it shall execute but finds none, as the line you try to run is uncommented (by the # in the beginning).
Because it found no code to evaluate it makes some noise.
Remove the # and it will work...